# Image Orientation on Camera API

Tags: android, camera, orientation

I am making an app using Camera API.Although I can capture images, they are not orientated properly.I already tried using screen orientation to correctly orient the images, but it dosent work on all devices especially on front camera.I am new to android development, any help would be appreciated.Thankyou.

Comment: Are you using the old camera API or camera2 API?

Comment: the old camera api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rotation of captured bitmap using [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface) and create another bitmap with fixed rotation - [here](https://gist.github.com/tomogoma/788e3b775dd611c9226f8e17781a0f0c) you can find example of usage. 
Moreover, I recommend to use [inBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options#inBitmap) option for reusing existing bitmap into created rotated one.

Camera1 and Camera2 APIs are kinda tricky ones.It is useful to know how they work inside but there are plenty of ready solutions. I can recommend the following ones:

- https://camerakit.io - has fixes for rotation issues inside but
  currently in beta, supports Camera2 features.
- https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat - based on Camera1.
- https://github.com/natario1/CameraView - based on Camera1, can
  capture video.

Comment: thankyou for your solution,it works on back camera...althought it misses out on front cam...any help would be appreciated...thankyou

Comment: You are welcome. Probably in provided example some cases are missed. I recommend to take a look at this example - https://gist.github.com/aviadmini/4be34097dfdb842ae066fae48501ed41 where flip, transverse, transpose orientations covered.

Comment: thank you so much sir....i got most of the part covered with your help....